# Facing error in Android websocket client while creating connection

Tags: android, websocket

Below code tried to connect to the Websocket server which is present on a LAN. I tried to access the webpage from the android device it works fine. But socket connection is not working

```
public class ClientConnection extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

    protected static final String TAG = "change";

    public static  void  initWebSocketClient() {
        Log.d(TAG,"init client websckt request");
        try {
            URI url = new URI("ws://ipadress:8080/WebSocketDemo1/serverEndpointDemo1");
            WebSocket websocket = new WebSocketConnection(url);

            // Register Event Handlers
            websocket.setEventHandler(new WebSocketEventHandler() {
                    public void onOpen()
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG,"OPEN");
                    }

                    public void onMessage(WebSocketMessage message)
                    {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Message");
                    }

                    public void onClose()
                    {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Close");
                    }
            });

            // Establish WebSocket Connection
            websocket.connect();

            // Send UTF-8 Text
            websocket.send("hello world");



            // Close WebSocket Connection
            websocket.close();
        }
        catch (WebSocketException wse) {
                wse.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                use.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        initWebSocketClient();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am making following call to get websocket connection..

```
try {
                //ClientConnection.getClientSession().getBasicRemote().sendObject(m);
                new ClientConnection().execute();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The error message I got is

```
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252): de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketException: error while creating socket to ws://ipadress:8080/WebSocketDemo1/serverEndpointDemo1
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketConnection.createSocket(WebSocketConnection.java:248)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketConnection.connect(WebSocketConnection.java:87)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at com.example.conn.ClientConnection.initWebSocketClient(ClientConnection.java:66)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at com.example.conn.ClientConnection.doInBackground(ClientConnection.java:87)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at com.example.conn.ClientConnection.doInBackground(ClientConnection.java:1)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-05 10:36:01.310: W/System.err(9252): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:724)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:150)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:176)
04-05 10:36:01.320: W/System.err(9252):     at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketConnection.createSocket(WebSocketConnection.java:242)
04-05 10:36:01.330: W/System.err(9252):     ... 10 more
```

Please suggest something to make this codeworking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you once check your portno of your lan while installing it or else try this code.

```
private void connectWebSocket() {
  URI uri;
  try {
    uri = new URI("ws://websockethost:8080");
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
  }
  mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
      Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
      mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s) {
      final String message = s;
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
          textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
        }
      });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
      Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
      Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
  };
  mWebSocketClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: theres now WebSocketClient(uri) method in autobahn

Comment: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Demo/EchoClient/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/echoclient/EchoClientActivity.java

code given here working for me but whenever i try to do mConnection.sendTExt...(text)
error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mconnection.sendtext just change it as mbconnection.sendtext and try it once or else check it in your web socket server